# Replace URLs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of over 3000 tweets in Notepad++. Almost all of them contain URLs, which I would like to replace.

For instance:

> I am eating apples http://example.com/def and I like it
>
> What is this guy's name http://example.org/xyz can anyone help me out

What I would like to do is replace all http://.... strings by the term "URL", so the tweets would look like:

> I am eating apples URL and I like it
>
> What is this guy's name URL can anyone help me out

Comment: Regular Expressions are your friends (sure, dealing with them can make you insane, but still, friends).

Comment: Tell me this is not for spam

Answer (score 2):

You can use following [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

In the **Replace** menu (**CTRL+H**) you can do the following:

- Find: `http[s]?\:\/\/.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-]+`
- Replace: `URL`
- Options: check the `Regular expression`

[EDITED]

Thanks [@Vinayak](https://superuser.com/users/167187/vinayak) this is RegEx that works by OP:

```
http[s]?\:\/\/.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\_?=%&#\-\+!]+
```

Comment: Your regex is broken: it matches `http:// whatever`, but doesn't match `https://google.com`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It matches `http:// whatever`, but doesn't match `http://example.com/test_url?id=deadbeef&user=Admin%20John`.

Comment: It works for these two examples, but if she had only two URLs to replace, she would simply do *Find & Replace* twice instead of asking a question. She needs a regex that will work for *any* URL.

Comment: This looks ugly, but works for me: `http[s]?\:\/\/.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\_?=%&#\-\+!]+` :)

Comment: @Vinayak yours worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @Vinayak I have edited my answer integrated your suggestion. Maybe you want rather add your RegEx as a separate answer?

Comment: @thesisstudent you're welcome. duDE that's fine, I don't want to add another answer